# container discovery in docker-compose

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I've the following docker-compose, how can moduleA find what IP or port the moduleB is running on so it can make a REST call to it.

question is how should I configure docker properties that moduleA get's the ip port of ModuleB

```
version: "3"

services:
  moduleA:
    image: jboss/wildfly
    ports:
      - 9080:8080
      - 9990:9990
      - 65193:65193
    volumes:
      - ./ModuleA/target/ModuleA.war:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/ModuleA.war
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=mongo
      - MONGO_PORT=27017
      - MONGO_USERNAME=myuser
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=mypass
      - MONGO_DATABASE=mydb
      - MONGO_AUTHDB=admin
    command: >
      bash -c "/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin#007 --silent && /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0"
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  moduleb:
    image: jboss/wildfly
    ports:
      - 9081:8080
      - 9991:9990
      - 65194:65193
    volumes:
      - ./ModuleB/target/ModuleB.war:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/ModuleB.war
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=mongo
      - MONGO_PORT=27017
      - MONGO_USERNAME=myuser
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=mypass
      - MONGO_DATABASE=mydb
    command: >
      bash -c "/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin#007 --silent && /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0"
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo


  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0.10
    container_name: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongouser
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mongopass
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
      - 27018:27018
      - 27019:27019
```

I've the ports hard coded, are we supposed to inject hard coded ports or how does it work?

Comment: How is the question any different than how the modules know where Mongo exists? You wouldn't use IPs, you would use the container service names & ports.

Comment: `moduleA` and `moduleb` are host names in a Docker Compose context and you can just use them.  The `links:` are unnecessary and you should probably remove them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link `moduleA` in `moduleB` same way you did for `mongo`. And then either use the same in your environment to define `MODULEA_HOST` or use in your properties file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, can you please upvote my question. not sure why someone didn't like it